# Why window onscroll event does not work?

Tags: javascript, events, onscroll

I want to execute the window `onscroll` event, but I don't know why it doesn't work on all browsers(firefox, chrome, etc), and there is no errors occurred.

**Full code:**

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('repeat');
var show = document.getElementById('show');

for (i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    elem.innerHTML += i + "<br/>";
}


window.onscroll = function () {
    show.innerHTML = document.body.scrollTop;
};
```

```css
#show {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:300px;
}
```

```html
<pre id="repeat"></pre>

<div style="position:relative;">
    <div id="show">x</div>
</div>
```

Also jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sqo0140j

**What is the problem ?**

Comment: Do you have enough content to scroll? http://jsfiddle.net/pfmqjcx2/

Comment: All seems fine to me. Can you create a jsfiddle so we can see the issue you're having please. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will not be able to reproduce it in fiddle. Which means this is something in your other code and it's not possible to help you.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: It's working fine, your fiddle AND your snippet - Chrome, Win8

Comment: Do you have any greasemonkey or tampermonkey scripts running in your browser?

Comment: @Drakes: there is no any greasemonkey or tampermonkey or something like that

Comment: This should be obvious but amazingly enough it often isn't. When you make an example of your problem you need to make sure the example replicates the issue you're having. A jsfiddle that works like it should isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: I'm still doesn't know what's wrong in my all browsers

Comment: No-one else can know either if no-one can see the problem.

Comment: Is you script references externally with the src attribute? IN that case it may not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You said something interesting:

> x changed to 0 and remains as is.

The only way in your code that can happen is if the `onscroll` function block makes a change because your HTML sets x.

If your `window.onscroll = function()` is indeed firing, but you are not getting the right scroll position (i.e. 0), try changing the way the scroll position is returned:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    show.innerHTML = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
};
```

I found out that `document.documentElement.scrollTop` always returns 0 on Chrome. This is because WebKit uses `body` for keeping track of scrolling, but Firefox and IE use `html`.

Please try your updated snippet:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('repeat');
var show = document.getElementById('show');

for (i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    elem.innerHTML += i + "<br/>";
}


window.onscroll = function () {
    show.innerHTML = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
};
```

```css
#show {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:300px;
}
```

```html
<pre id="repeat"></pre>

<div style="position:relative;">
    <div id="show">x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you run this snippet?

Comment: Works fine, but when copy this code to my editor and run it on my browsers, still does not works.

Comment: So, the snippet works in your browser, but your offline file doesn't work in the same browser?

Comment: We're going to have to see your HTML in your offline file. Can you post it to like pastebin.com?

Comment: Finally, I knew the problem -> in my css  `html, body {margin:0;}`. when remove `margin:0;`, the code works fine.

Comment: lol! But you had no `html, body {margin:0;}` in the snippet. You should write up your own answer for anyone who stumbles upon a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, and for that reason the code was works fine. and I'm forgot add it in the snippet.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you for continued help me, and you will take the best answer.

Comment: I'll leave my answer to help others who might have the Chrome issue - And thanks man!

Comment: @Lion King Holly cow! The margin zero saved my life... thanks!!!!! In my case also I had heigth:100% too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For me the statement `document.body.scrollTop;` works well in Chrome and Opera, but on Firefox returns 0.

Viceversa the statement `document.documentElement.scrollTop;` works good on Firefox but not in Chrome and Opera...

Maybe `document.body.scrollTop;` is not well supported by FF

### Possible Solutions:

I tried:

```
Math.max(document.body.scrollTop, document.documentElement.scrollTop);
```

and

```
 document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

They both works well on all above browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same problem , but I didn't know the proper reason for that .
In my case

```
window.onscroll = function () {
   console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
 };
```

this code didn't work even after removing `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` .
But by mention the addEventListener on the document.body it is worked

```
document.body.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
  console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered, but I wanted to include details of my situation that prevent onscroll from working.

I have datacontainer that had its own scroll bar which overrides the built in window scroll bar. I didnt notice this until I started giving a more thorough look at the elements on the page using chrome developer. My outer tag looked like this,

This caused two scroll bars to appear on the left. This was because the property, overflow:auto, was telling the data container to make another scroll bar.

Once I removed the overflow:auto I could now correct hit the onscroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Because a lot of people use W3Schools i wanted to leave this here.
This simple scroll event wasn't firing

```
   window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset - 20 >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky");
        }
    }
```

Until I removed     < link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
and everything was working again flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

For people having issues with this function. Another reason that it looks like it is not working is that you define it multiple times.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log('scroll 1');
};

// some other js code

window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log('scroll 2');
};
```

Only the last one gets executed since it overwrites your first declaration. The solution is then

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log('scroll 1');
})

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log('scroll 2');
})
```